# How can I access the application version?

Tags: iphone, ios, version, bundle

I would like to know how can I access the iOS application target version.

[This number : http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/146187Capturedcran20110728111355.png](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/146187Capturedcran20110728111355.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSDictionary* infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString* versionNum = [infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

This will give the version number. Similarly you can get other attributes as well.

Comment: Thanks Praveen S, it's not the first time you help me !

Comment: This seems to not work (any more). It returns the Build number, not Version.

Comment: `Build Number is at: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]

Version Number is at: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]`